# Mesh is gone after Bool Tool undo

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I've played around with the Bool Tools, but when I remove the created modifier from the stack, my object mesh is gone. Not really gone, I see Cube.002's edges there in Edit mode, but I cannot get it to display again. Also there still is this cube around my mesh, left over from Bool Tools.

How can I completely undo a not-yet-applied Bool Tool operation?

[image: Mesh gone missing, presumed having a good time]

[Link to Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z0cN6PLeKAO7_xiuxelw9D_rY2aJirBT/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Is Cube.002 the object you think is gone?  If it is, select it and go to its Object properties and see what Viewport Display -> Display As is set to.  It'll probably be "Wire" or "Bounds."  Change it to "Textured".  Otherwise, please add your .blend file to the question.

Comment: Ah ok, that was it. Seems it is set to "Bounds" by BoolTools and when removing the modifier from the stack it stays as Bounds. Have to know where to look for it :-) You want to put that as the answer?

Comment: Sure.  I'll clean it up and make an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BoolTool changes the way an object is displayed in the 3D window so that you can see the effect of the Boolean operation without the object getting in the way.  It looks like when you undid the BoolTool operation the object remained displayed as "Bounds."

Here's how to check this:

In the properties editor, in the "Object Properties" tab there is a "Viewport Display" item.  Open it and it will show you a list of things that are displayed about the object:

[image: Viewport Display]

The next to last item is "Display As". This has a drop down menu:

[image: Display as drop down]

If you leave it as "Textured", then you get the normal behavior where the 3D menu for scene display decides whether to show the wire frame, solid, textured, or rendered view, via:

[image: display mode menu]

But if you set it to one of the other values, then it will display the object as no more that that form.

BoolTool does something fairly common in the Boolean based modeling workflow so as to avoid confusing you. Here's an example of a Boolean where I am using a cylinder to cut a hole in the default box:

[image: Cylinder used to cut a hole]

Because the cylinder is still visible, you can't see the hole in the cube.  So BoolTool and other boolean based workflows like hardops or boxcutter set the cylinder to only display as wireframe or bounding box:

[image: cylinder displayed as wire frame]

[image: cylinder displayed as bounding box]